# How to find last-added USB device in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, usb, troubleshooting, device-manager

Is there a way to find the last-added USB device in Windows (perhaps something like "dmesg" for Windows)?

I'm plugging the USB device in, and it makes the sound of connection, but when I check Device Manager -- it's not there (where I think it should be), nor is there any notification of malfunctioning devices.

I've tried looking through similar and neighboring categories in Device Manager, but I can't find the thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.

In order to determine the last time the device was connected to the system, we have to navigate to the following Registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses`.

**DeviceClasses** Contains information about the device interfaces on the system. There is a subkey for each device interface class and entries under those subkeys for each instance of an interface that is registered for the device interface class.

[Read more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Or use [**USBDeview**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html).

> USBDeview is a small utility that lists all USB devices that currently
>   connected to your computer, as well as all USB devices that you
>   previously used.

[image]

<sub>[`See Reference`](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/USB_History_Viewing)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Just for future reference -- what should I be looking for within that registry key? I see a smorgasbord of GUID's, but seemingly no sort order (like by date).

Answer (score 7):

I should have googled a second longer before posting :)

There's a free application called "USBDeview" that does just this, with the ability to sort on last plug/unplug date.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

And if this one didn't work, I was about to next try another free utility called "USBLogView", which shows USB information for any device that is plugged/unplugged from the system while the utility is open.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html

I found the device just fine, labeled with a nicely generic "USB Input Device", rather than the actual product and model name (which appears just fine in USBDeview).

Comment: USBDeview is hard to follow, too much info. Also I did not see any column called "last plug" or "last unplug" nor did I see a setting for it. The usb_log_view did the trick though.