# View logs for device/port power management events to find/identify which device is going into power savings?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

If I don't use my machine for a few minutes, I hear the device disconnect sound. The computer never went to sleep and screensaver doesn't start.

If I move the mouse or touch the keyboard the device connect sound happens.

I assume there is some kind of device/port power savings but I cannot figure out what it is.

I have disabled all power savings features that I can think of.

Is there some log I can view somewhere to see what is going on/offline and/or power savings?

I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any edition of windows 10 *except* Home, you can enable plug-and-play audit events when devices get connected, and get the device ID from event viewer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-6416

Otherwise, you could try a third-party tool like usbdview: [How to find last-added USB device in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/659358/how-to-find-last-added-usb-device-in-windows)

Or capture+display those events yourself with powershell: [How to log "new pnp devices" events to console on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650486/how-to-log-new-pnp-devices-events-to-console-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

The auditing of device connect and disconnect is disabled by default.

To enable :

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Drill-down to
  *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings >
  Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > System Audit Policies >
  Detailed Tracking*
- Double-click "Audit PNP Activity"
- Check both "Success" and "Failure"
- Click OK.

Next set up an event filter for
EventID 6416 - A new external device was recognized by the system:

- Run the Event Viewer
- Click on the right "Create Custom View..."
- Click "By source" and find and check
  "Microsoft Windows security auditing"
- Click in the field "" and enter `6416`
- Click OK
- Enter a name, for example "Event 6416"
- Click OK.

Cause the connect sound to happen and look at the event filter that
you created.

You will need to locate the device by the information inside this
event. If you need help, click on the "Details" tab, then on
"XML view", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select
everything and paste it inside your post.

Useful article :
[6416(S): A new external device was recognized by the System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-6416).